# I QUERY [conn487] assertion 13 not authorized for query on

Tags: java, mongodb

When I tried to connect to MongoDB3.0 from a Java Service, there is an error

```
2015-04-04T07:39:15.008+0800 I QUERY    [conn487] assertion 13 not authorized for query on....
```

In fact, I can use my username to query `directly` in MongoDB. Also, I can use this username to finish CRUD operations by my Node.js application.
Of course, It's a simple MongoDB, no replication.

I set up duplicated usernames in admin and my database, I granted this user all the privileges and actions( `actions: [ "find","insert","remove","update" ]`).

I have no idea what's wrong with my java service.

this is my mongo configuration file.

```
port = 27017 
fork = true 
auth = true 
directoryperdb = true 
nohttpinterface = true
```

my mongo-java-driver is 3.0.0.

I've Googled it, but I can't find the solution.
Thank you so much.

Comment: What version of the Java driver are you using, and what version of MongoDB? Can you show us a bit of code for how you authenticate in Java?

Comment: thanks, I just resolved the problem. Thank you so much

Comment: @jason516 how did you resolved your problem?

Comment: @Jason516 how did you resolved it?

Comment: HOW DID YOU RESOLVE THIS?